# Is there scientific value in recreating existing papers in natural language processing for further languages?

Tags: research-process

For example, if a sarcasm detection (or sentiment analysis or any other similar NLP problem in that matter) paper has already been produced for tweets/news/media in English, will there be any scientific value if I try to do the same thing but for tweets/news/media in another language, such as Albanian.

I have an idea on where to get the data, and there isn't any previous research on these matters (or NLP in general) specifically to Albanian. Is it worth me doing a paper about it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, there is scientific value in the project you describe. When writing the paper, be sure to highlight any special handling you had to do for Albanian (or whatever language you choose). It will be interesting to compare the accuracy of the approach applied to Albanian vs. English.

It is possible (though I suspect it's unlikely)  that you might end up with results that simply validate that the approach works the exactly same in Albanian as well as English, and there's nothing more to say. That would still have scientific merit, but might be a little more difficult to publish in the higher-tier venues. If that happens, you could publish in a lower-tier venue (nothing to be ashamed of, as long as it's a legitimate conference/journal). Or you could make the topic more interesting by applying the approach to more than one language.

Comment: Further, if it the same model *doesn't* work for Albanian and English, the reasons *why* and the changes you make to work in Albanian may provide the insight needed to produce somewhat that does work for all (or at least more) languages.

Comment: And, if the approach does work equally well in Albanian then hopefully the research won't take too long, so it's less vexing if you can't find anywhere to publish.